# What's the caller in this case and what will happen if I pass exception to the caller?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

> **Q.**    Suppose the statement2 causes an exception in following try-catch block:
>
> ```
> try {
>   statement1;
>   statement2;
>   statement3;
> }
> catch(Exception1 e1) {
> }
> catch(Exception2 e2){
> }
>   
> statement4;
> ```
>
> Answer the following question:
>
> - If the exception is passed to the caller, will the statement4 be executed?

I didn't have any idea about "caller", so I searched and found this:

> Simply put, "caller" is basically what the standard English
> interpretation of the term implies.  When we talk about "a method's
> caller", we mean the the code that called (invoked) that method.
> Depending on the context, we might be referring to the specific line
> or statement that executes the method  call, or to the method,
> constructor, or initialization block that contains that line.

So with this definition of caller, what's the caller in my question and what will happen if I pass exception to caller?

Comment: It's not very clear, since "called" implies that a function is being called, but there's no function here. Also, you don't typically "pass" exceptions unless you're processing an exception or saving it or something; but I don't think that that's what they're referring to. I think it means if an exception is "thrown"?

Comment: I suppose the question aims at the understanding, that when an Exception other than Exception1 or Exceptione2 is thrown, it will be passed to the caller and statement 4 will not be executed

Answer (score 0):

simple answer for above question is statement4 will be executed because statement4 is out of the try catch-block but I don't understand what you mean by caller.

If there is a error in statement2 it won't execute statment3 instead it will directly jump to catch after that statment4 will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the exception thrown by statement2 that is passed to the caller, this means it is not an exception of type Exception1 or Exception2. In that case statement4 is not executed.

But you can also capture the exception, store it in a variable and rethrow it after statement4:

```
Exception ex=null;
try {
    statement1;
    statement2;
    statement3;
}
catch(Exception1 e1) {
  ex=e1;
}
catch(Exception2 e2){
}
  
statement4;
if (ex!=null)
    throw ex;
```

In the latter case, statement4 is executed.